# The use of 'or' in a list after 'without': Does this suggest uncertainty?

Tags: meaning-in-context, conjunctions, punctuation

[Source](http://www.pressreader.com/india/the-times-of-india-new-delhi-edition/20160529/282540132585148)

> He's been the bowler of this IPL: quiet, still, without flaring nostrils, piercing gaze **or** arching eyebrows.

Why is **or** used there? The writer unsure of what he's saying?

Comment: Please include a link to the text you quote.

Comment: Added source over there.

Comment: Also note that the comma before *or* is not as important as the comma before *without*, which is somehow missing in your sentence.

Comment: There **is** a comma after still in the source you link to.

Comment: Why 'or' used there?

Comment: It uses ***or*** because the alternative *without A, B, **and** C* could be interpreted to mean that he *might* have only one or two of the three things (in which case the statement would still be true; he just doesn't have ***all three***). There is no such ambiguity with ***or*** - it definitely means he doesn't have ***any*** of them. Even so. native speakers sometimes use the ambiguous form anyway. Either because they don't *care* about the distinction, or because context makes it obvious how the list should be interpreted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q: You asked, "Why (is) *or* used there? The writer (is) unsure of what he's saying?"
A: No. It's not like the writer was uncertain about the characters of this bowler.

---

Before explaining the use of *or* in your sentence, I'd like to invite you to consider a simpler example:

> 1) *He is dark, tall, and handsome.*
>   2) *She's not boring, lazy, or dull.*

1) lists three things that he is. He is dark. He is tall. He is handsome, too!
2) lists three things that she is not. She isn't boring. She isn't lazy. She isn't dull, either.

This is probably the most common way to write lists in affirmative and negative sentences.
In mathematics, as you may recall, `NOT (A AND B)` equals `(NOT A) OR (NOT B)`.
That's probably why it's natural that way. (Then again, language is not math.)

---

Back to your original sentence:

> *He's been the bowler of this IPL: quiet, still, without flaring nostrils, piercing gaze or arching eyebrows.*

The sentence lists three things about him:
a) he's been quiet, b) he's been still, and c) he's been so without three expressions.

The three expressions (that he's been without) are:
c1) flaring nostrils, c2) piercing gaze, and c3) arching eyebrows.